# With sufficient specs and Intel® VT enabled, Android Emulator and Genymotion both lag when they're running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

When I first started using the emulator than came with Android Studio, it was running very sluggish even with HAXM enabled. I decided to play around with the RAM allowance along with switching between the Software and Hardware option but no dice. I decided later to install Genymotion due to the good reviews and it runs as slow as it does with the other emulator. I've also checked to see if Intel VT was enabled and it was. I also don't run any major applications during the emulation.

I've tried a number of methods and I've yet to find and fix this problem of the poor performance of these emulators.

The processor I'm using is a quad core i5-6300HQ with 8 gigs of ram and a GTX960M graphics card. Windows, Genymotion, and Android Studio (with its SDKs) are all installed onto an SSD.

Is there a method of fixing this that I've missed?

Thanks.

The Resolution I'm using is 1440x2560.

Comment: What is the resolution/density settings of the emulator images you have having lag on?

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for responding; I've updated the resolution on the post.

Comment: Honestly I think you are trying too high a resolution as it more than most monitors that would normally be attached to a mobile graphics chip. Consider it as driving a second screen with those specs. For regular use I would recommend 1080x1920 or lower as you won't notice the difference if the emulator is in a window. And still use higher spec emulators sparingly to check on high density layouts and assets.

Comment: Make sure you update your graphics drivers. Looking at the Nvidia website, there are 2017 driver updates. Assuming you are using x86 emulator system image, the official Android Emulator uses GPU acceleration and up to date drivers are critical for better performance.